# Power Query: add custom column formula for text file to table

Tags: excel, powerquery

I used `=Excel.Workbook([Content])` in custom column formula to extract my workbooks as table but now I have other files as .TXT . Is there any similar code to `=Excel.Workbook([Content])` but for text files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, it is `= Csv.Document([Content],[Delimiter=":"])`. it returns my text file as table

Answer (score 1):

There is a connector for txt/CSV files.
For more details see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/textcsv